# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host on WCF

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, windows-server-2008-r2

We are getting following issue in our Production environment only. rest of environments its working fine.

we checked various links on stackoverflow but nothing worked.

- tried increasing `

> ```
> <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
> ```

- increased timeout
- put tracing, but even that not showing any specific issue

  ```
   [SocketException (0x2746): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
      System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +245

   [IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.]
      System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +7867549
      System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +22
      System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead) +408

   [WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.]
      System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +7870788
      System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +99

   [CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://myservice/Service.svc. This could be due to
   the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could
   also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
   (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more
   details.]
      System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +4728419
      System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +1725
      MyService.ISSO.ProcessRequest(SSORequest request) +0
  ```

Comment: This could be caused by an unhandled exception in your service, causing the service to shut down.  Have you looked in the event viewer to see if there are any errors logged for the service?

Comment: @Techmaster did you discover a root cause or solution to this?

Comment: @n00b no i couldn't :(

Answer (score 0):

"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

This error could be generated because of **Group Policy Settings**. Try connecting to Analysis Service using SQL Management Studio, if error persist try to **elevate the user privilages**.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this. How does one connect to SQL Management studio on the hosting server? which user does one elevate user privileges for?